# Probability of full house?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

I have seen there are other answers on this, but they all follow the pattern

1. first, choose which card you have $3$ of
2. then, choose $3$ of the $4$ available cards
3. then, the card you have $2$ of
4. then, $2$ of $4$ cards

and they get to

$$\binom{13}{1} \binom{4}{3} \binom{12}{1} \binom{4}{2}$$

for the numerator.

My question is: doesn't this imply some kind of ordering?

By following the same logic, I would think that for the denominator

1. pick any of $52$ cards
2. then, pick any of $51$ remaining cards

and so on, getting $52 \cdot 51 \cdot 50 \cdot 49 \cdot 48$. But instead, the correct value of the denominator is $\binom{52}{5}$.

Why are those cases different?

Comment: There is no order imposed by the construction. A full house is determined by the rank of the triple, the suits within that rank, the rank of the pair, the suits within that rank.  No order involved.

Comment: By contrast, your second calculation does impose an order...since you choose the first card, then the second, and so on.

Comment: @lulu: i realise that for the second calculation, but I don't see why the first one does not. how could I visualize it?

Comment: Work with a smaller hand.  Say you want to count the two card hands consisting of an ace and a queen.  There are four ways to choose the ace and four to choose the queen, so $4\times 4=16$.  If you order them, there are $32$.

Comment: @lulu: thank you

Comment: Build up from two cards.  Say I want to count the unordered hands with two spades and a heart.  Convince yourself that this is $\binom {13}2\times \binom {13}1$.